# Determine the next two numbers in a number series

Tags: number-sequence

What are the next 2 numbers in the series `1, 1, 2, 4,6, 18, 21, 84, ?, ?`

Please give a valid reason to justify your answer.

Comment: This sequence can be directly looked-up on http://oeis.org/A019464

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The next two numbers in the series are:

> 88, 440

The series is:

> *1, +1, *2, +2, *3, +3, *4, +4, *5, +5, etc.